# No matching provisioning profiles found after having used Xcode 8 beta

Tags: xcode

I have downloaded and used Xcode 8 beta, and uploaded my app to the Appstore with that. That didn't work because of it being from a beta version of Xcode, however after I tried to open the same project in Xcode 7 again, I got the "No matching provisioning profiles found"-error when archiving and trying to re-upload. How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

I used half a day trying to figure this out, so thought I should post it here in case someone else gets into the same problems.

I tried just about every solution I found here, but nothing worked. I ended up going back in my git-history finding that when I had used Xcode 8, it had added two of these lines to my project.pbxproj file:

```
DEVELOPMENT_TEAM = XXXXXXX
```

After deleting these lines (reversing the hunks in my commit-history) everything worked as normal.